# Format XmlDocument (indentation) without removing line breaks

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xml-formatting

I have an XML file that I want to modify (add new elements) and then save. The problem is that the file has empty lines that should not be deleted.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```cs
// loading document with PreserveWhiteSpace = true
var doc = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true };
doc.Load(inputFilePath);

// add a new element to the document
var el = doc.CreateElement("TestElement");
doc.InsertAfter(el, doc["SomeParentElement"]["SomeChildElement"]);

// save document
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
  Indent = true,
  IndentChars = @"  ",
  NewLineChars = "\r\n",
  NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
  OmitXmlDeclaration = true
};

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputFilePath, settings))
{
  doc.Save(writer);
}
```

I'm setting the documents `PreserveWhitespace` to true before loading, so that the line breaks do not get ignored. Because of this, the new element I'm adding after the `doc["SomeParentElement"]["SomeChildElement"]` does not start on a new line and, if I add the newline myself, does not have the correct indentation.
I tried many of the settings in XmlWriterSetting, but nothing in there seemed to work when `PreserveWhitespace` is set to true.

Is it possible to insert a new element into an xml file and save it with a nice formatting but without deleting empty lines in the document?

Example:

```xml
<SomeParentElement>
  <SomeChildElement/>

  <SomeChildElement2/>
  <SomeChildElement3/>
</SomeParentElement>
```

Should look like this after running the code above:

```xml
<SomeParentElement>
  <SomeChildElement/>
  <TestElement/>

  <SomeChildElement2/>
  <SomeChildElement3/>
</SomeParentElement>
```

Comment: How about making the empty lines comments?

Comment: @jdweng the source document should keep the empty lines. Only thing would be to replace the empty lines with comments before making changes and then replacing them with empty lines again after... would be possible but I had hoped there would be a better way. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I'd generally suggest LINQ to XML is a far nicer API. You can insert the whitespace you need to keep the formatting you want. For example:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Load(inputFilePath, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

var child = doc.Elements("SomeParentElement").Elements("SomeChildElement").First();

child.AddAfterSelf(
    new XText("\r\n  "),
    new XElement("TestElement"));

doc.Save(outputFilePath);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uDpugF) for a working demo.

Comment: Xml Linq will not fix the problem since it uses the same XmlWriter with same options as OPs code.

Comment: You're right, Linq Xml seems nicer. But your solution doesn't work either, you still have to know how much to indent the new element and do it yourself. In my case, I don't know that and would rather just format the whole document without removing newlines. But thanks anyway

Comment: @TobiasZaugg yes, you'd have to know. There's no significance to the whitespace between XML elements, so as far as the tooling is concerned your requirement is completely arbitrary. If you want your new element to match, you'll have to add that whitespace.

Comment: @jdweng not sure that's relevant. Those settings aren't the same in this case, but in either case they will be ignored because whitespace is preserved in the DOM. This approach does provide a solution to the problem, though it may not be what was hoped for.